# Using Apple ID On Personal & Work Phone

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, ios, iphone

What services should sync when I log into iCloud & use the same Apple ID on both my work phone & personal iPhone?

Currently I am seeing calls appear on both phones. iMessages do not appear on both phones. iCloud photos do appear on both. Notes do not appear on both.

Seems that it's advertised as syncing all but doesn't actually work.

Comment: There are about 8 places in settings where you can log in with different AppleIds, sounds like you only iCloud is the same on both.

Comment: Personally, under no circumstances whatsoever would I ever login into personal accounts of any kind on a employer owned work device! I've had friends fired when some of what was in their personal digital dust found on their employers devices by the IT staff and passed on to the boss. Just a word of warning if applicable. :)